# dataSource.RecordCount in a mailMerge

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I'm trying to use a macro I found online to save each doc from a mail merge into an individual PDF. But the macro does nothing. (never used macros before or VB) I tried stepping through the code and I get `.DataSource.RecordCount = -1`.
I can see the previewed documents, so the datasource is there. I figure there is something wrong with how it's getting the count value.
Any help is appreciated.

This is the whole macro:

```
Sub Merge_To_Individual_Files()
' Sourced from: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFolder As String, StrName As String, MainDoc As Document, i As Long, j As Long
Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|"
Set MainDoc = ActiveDocument
With MainDoc
  StrFolder = .Path & "\"
  With .MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To .DataSource.RecordCount
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = i
        .LastRecord = i
        .ActiveRecord = i
        If Trim(.DataFields("Last_Name")) = "" Then Exit For
        'StrFolder = .DataFields("Folder") & "\"
        StrName = .DataFields("key")
      End With
      On Error GoTo NextRecord
      .Execute Pause:=False
      For j = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
        StrName = Replace(StrName, Mid(StrNoChr, j, 1), "_")
      Next
      StrName = Trim(StrName)
      With ActiveDocument
        'Add the name to the footer
        '.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InsertBefore StrName
        .SaveAs FileName:=StrFolder & StrName & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        ' and/or:
        .SaveAs FileName:=StrFolder & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
      End With
NextRecord:
    Next i
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What OS are you using? The RecordCount property isn't supported on Macs.

Comment: See, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921973/word-mail-merge-recordcount-returns-1 . You can get a -1 count for other reasons than the ones mentioned there, e.g. if your query contains a LIKE clause. NB, setting .ActiveRecord to .LastRecord as suggested there is not instantaneous and can take quite a long time for a large record count.