get total number of records in a mail merge through vba
hello all I am trying to write some VBA code that willinteract with a word document that has been set-up as a mail merge.
the document is all set-up, including attaching the mail mergedata ( in this case from a csv file and the mail merge field added to the document. when opening the document the user is present with the dialog box " opening this document will run the following SQL command
SELECT * FROM  DATA SOURCE FILE PATH which is as expected.
once yes is clicked the user can goto th 'mailings' tab press 'preview results' and the document will load the preview results into the relevant fields and they can scroll along the availble record right to the end - in he example I'm working with 6 records.
I'm using the following code to try an do some custom vba code interaction on this mail merge and one of the variables  I need is the total number of records available in the attached mail merge.
so far I have the code:
Set doc = ActiveDocument
Set myMerge = doc.MailMerge
total records = myMerge.DataSource.RecordCount

however  the end resultthat comes out is -1
when I know and the word application itself knows that the attached merge data source has 6 available records that can be accessed
I've done some research and I've found reports that -1 is the returned number when the data source can't be accessed properly, however I KNOW that it can accessed because in a different section of the code I use the following code to put the available mail merge fields in to a combo box on a user form. so I know the data source is attached and can be accessed.
    With doc.MailMerge
cmbkey.AddItem .DataSource.FieldNames(i).Name


See this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921973/word-mail-merge-recordcount-returns-1

@Halukput this in as an answer and I'll vote it as correct and close my question. or if some one knows how they could mark my question as a duplicate and link it to the question you've added above. thanks very much.
